# Android: authorize application to connect to twitter

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am using twitter4j and the following code:

```
public static void OAuthLogin(Activity a) {
    try {
        twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        twitter.setOAuthConsumer(key, secret);
        RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(CALLBACK);
        String authUrl = requestToken.getAuthenticationURL();
        a.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authUrl)));
    } catch (TwitterException ex) {
        Log.e("in Main.OAuthLogin", ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

and getting

`401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid conumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock in in sync.`

when executing `twitter.getOAuthRequestToken()` Once I remove `CALLABACK` param everything's fine - I am redirected to twitter login page where I can get PIN. The thing is that I do not want the user to deal with the PIN and be brought back to the app instead. How do I achieve that?

**EDIT:** found what's causing the problem and modified the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You MUST set [dummy] callback URL on application page @ twitter!

Comment: HI,  when i tried i got Socket Time out Exception              11-20 13:33:11.679: WARN/System.err(3308): The operation timed outTwitterException{exceptionCode=[8dda30a8-61299907 8dda30a8-612998dc], statusCode=-1, retryAfter=0, rateLimitStatus=null, version=2.1.6}
11-20 13:33:11.679: WARN/System.err(3308): Caused by: java.net.SocketException: The operation timed out

Answer (score 0):

Try to also set this right after setOAuthConsumer:

```
twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(AccessToken(token, tokenSecret));
```

Hope this helps

-serkan